# Running JAX-RS in Netbeans 8.1 EJB project

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans, ejb, jax-rs

I created a `Java EE 7` application using `Netbeans 8.1` (Maven project), having an EJB project and a Web project. I added an `ApplicationConfig` extending `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` and marked auto-generated `NewSessionBean` with `javax.ws.rs.GET` and `javax.ws.rs.Path` in the EJB project.

Now, when I right click on the EJB project and RUN it, it gets deployed on the Glassfish server, but I can't access REST resource. Here is the JAX-RS config file:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JaxrsAppConfig extends Application {

}
```

Here is my JAX-RS resource:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("/demo")
public class NewSessionBean {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Person businessMethod() {
        return new Person(1, "Prakhar Mishra", 26);
    }
}
```

I tried to access it using these URLs:

```
http://localhost:8080/DemoJavaEE7-ejb/api/demo
http://localhost:8080/DemoJavaEE7-web/api/demo
http://localhost:8080/api/demo
```

But, getting regular 404 page. Could anybody please tell me what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You should registered you service.
Try to change your config like:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        packages("org.foo.rest;org.bar.rest");
    }
}
```

More details https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html